# Disable/Remove floating label hint text in TextInputLayout XML

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

This may seem counter-intuitive but is there a way to disable or remove the floating label hint in `TextInputLayout`? The reason I want to use `TextInputLayout` instead of just an `EditText` is for the counter that `TextInputLayout` provides.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="100">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/myEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:hint="This is my cool hint"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Best idea to programatically you have to give hint and textChange event time Give to null hint in editbox that idea may help you

Comment: Problem is the hint color. It becomes white when typing something. Please change the hint color or change the background color. You will see the hint while typing.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Starting version 23.2.0 of the Support Library you can call

```
setHintEnabled(false)
```

or putting it in your TextInputLayout xml as such :

```
app:hintEnabled="false"
```

Though the name might makes you think it removes all hints, it just removes the floating one.

Related docs and issue: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintEnabled(boolean)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181590

Comment: I'm having this hide the error as well, which is a little unexpected (version 27.1.1)

Comment: Extra note: In order for this to work, you need to set the hint on the `TextInputEditText`. If you set the hint on the `TextInputLayout` it won't be shown.

Comment: But it adds some strange padding on top when you set app:hintEnabled="false"
 :( If you use icons on the right, it will be noticeable. I've added paddingTop="12dp" to TextInputEditText, it looks fine then.

Comment: I don't know why android decided to change what a hint is, they should have referenced the label with another property.

Answer (score 66):

There may be three ways to go about achieving this:

**1** Set `android:hint` on `TextInputLayout` to a space `_` character, and keep `android:hint="This is my cool hint"` set on the `EditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ....
    ....
    android:hint=" ">       <<----------

    <EditText
        ....
        ....
        android:hint="This is my cool hint"/>    <<----------

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This works because `TextInputLayout` performs the following check before using the `EditText's` hint:

```
// If we do not have a valid hint, try and retrieve it from the EditText
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mHint)) {
    setHint(mEditText.getHint());
    // Clear the EditText's hint as we will display it ourselves
    mEditText.setHint(null);
}
```

By setting `android:hint=" "`, `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mHint))` evaluates to `false`, and the `EditText` retains its hint.

**2** Second option would be to subclass `TextInputLayout` and override its `addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)` method:

```
public class CTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    public CTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            // cache the actual hint
            CharSequence hint = ((EditText)child).getHint();
            // remove the hint for now - we don't want TextInputLayout to see it
            ((EditText)child).setHint(null);
            // let `TextInputLayout` do its thing
            super.addView(child, index, params);
            // finally, set the hint back
            ((EditText)child).setHint(hint);
        } else {
            // Carry on adding the View...
            super.addView(child, index, params);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use your custom `CTextInoutLayout` instead of the one from the design support library:

```
<your.package.name.CTextInputLayout
    ....
    .... >       <<----------

    <EditText
        ....
        ....
        android:hint="This is my cool hint"/>    <<----------

</your.package.name.CTextInputLayout>
```

**3** Third, and probably the most straight-forward way would be to make the following calls:

```
// remove hint from `TextInputLayout`
((TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.textContainer)).setHint(null);
// set the hint back on the `EditText`
// The passed `String` could also be a string resource
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText)).setHint("This is my cool hinttt.");
```

Comment: This actually is solution for one more problem. When you set app:hintEnabled="false", you can get strange bug - top or bottom line of the box (with OutlinedBox style) is cut or even missing. CTextInputLayout is perfect solution for this bug. (I am using material:1.0.0, and tested on material:1.1.0 alfa 1 and 2)

Answer (score 36):

With  com.google.android.material you can hide by

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

               ....

               app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
               app:hintEnabled="false"
               >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    ........
                    android:hint="@string/label_hint"
                    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

I've tried all of answers, but non of them are working now (specifically for com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01). Even if we make changes to EditText addition logic in TextInputLayout, we have empty space on top of field that blanking half of text and hint. Now I have a solution for the problem. Main thing is a padding in EditText, as [mentioned](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/) in material.io:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
             . . .
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_search_black"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/showcase_search_hint_text"
        android:inputType="text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

It allows us to implement a 'SearchView'-like view with search icon and text deletion button without any ugly "magic" with custom views

Comment: using  android:paddingVertical="10dp" is better

Comment: See https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/366 to change padding between drawable and hint.

Comment: To achieve same overall height as with hint, android:paddingVertical="16dp" looks more like it

Answer (score 8):

if you have used app:hintEnabled="false" then also set android:paddingTop="8dp" in EditText and boom top hint space is gone, this worked for me hope this works for you too

Comment: Looks like there is no built-in way to fill hint space, thanks for the hack!

Answer (score 3):

If someone have problems like me:

[image: Bug lable padding]

The label make the text padding show wrong then do this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

Add padding top and padding bottom to the `TextInputEditText` that will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Gauthier is correct, but in case you don't want just the floating Hint but you want the Hint before text edit then in addition to disabling Hint for TextInputLayout you should provide hint in EditText widget.

I guess this answers few of the question raised by some people in above comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) textContainer.hint = null
            else myEditText.hint = getString(R.string.your_string)
        }
```

it makes your hint gone perfectly in your textInputLayout, because if you want to make it gone with app:hintEnabled="false" that's make your textInputLayout not cool :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etemailLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint=" ">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtemail"
                style="@style/login_edittext"
                android:hint="Enter Your Email Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint=" "
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtpassword"
                style="@style/login_edittext"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu"
                android:hint="Enter Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

for apply style to your EditText put below code in Styles.xml ..

```
<style name="login_edittext">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

for backgroud effect create edittext_background.xml in drawable..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    <solid android:color="#80ffffff" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Comment: This is easiest way to apply Hint but don't show it on upside when user clicks on EditeText.

Comment: Must Try This Solution, It Will Not Have Any Error In Code. And No Need To Change Code.Directly Put This Code.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you:

```
textContainer.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Does not work my friend. I tried in code and via XML `app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"` and neither worked. I think this just disables the animation of that label floating up.

Comment: So, you want to remove hint text, is it?

Comment: I want the hint text to appear inside of the `EditText` faded. Then when you click the `EditText` I want the hint text to disappear, instead of moving up to the floating label. Just like a regular `EditText` does it.

Answer (score -1):

update the design library to v23 and add `app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"` in the `TextInputLayout`